# Check if a key exists in JSON with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am using the Retrofit library and have a JSON response in  which a particular key is sometimes present. How do I check in my adapter whether that key exists or not?

Comment: Check if the value is `null` before using the value.

Comment: @KNeerajLal I tried that, doesn't work for me.

Comment: And what might be the reason for that?